# ASP NET MVC How to call Count on an attribute then print out a sorted list?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-entities

Say I had a class:

```
public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Topic { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(5000)]
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Votes { get; set; }
}
```

And for each post, a user could input a topic. for example, if the topics were "Red" "Green" "Blue" and "Yellow", how could I create a list based on how many times those were used?

An example output:

```
Red   | 70
Blue  | 60
Green | 40
Yellow| 35
```

EDIT: How come this doesn't work and gives me an error where I cannot implicitly convert the type?

```
public List<string> GetPopularTopics(int count)
    {
        var posts = from p in db.Posts
                    group p by p.Topic into myGroup
                    select new
                    {
                        Topic = myGroup.Key,
                        Count = myGroup.Count()
                    };
        return posts.ToList();
    }
```

EDIT 2:

So I tried your solution out Dustin, and I'm getting an error. This is what I used:

```
public IEnumerable<IGrouping<string,int>> GetPosts()
    {
        var posts = from p in db.Posts
                    group p by p.Topic into topicCounts
                    select new
                    {
                        Topic = topicCounts.Key,
                        Count = topicCounts.Count()
                    };
        return posts.ToList();
    }
```

This is giving me an error under posts.ToList(): 
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Would there be several *topics* on each post? Like the *tags* they have here on SO?

Comment: no just one topic for each post

Comment: Ok, Dustin Laine has the solution for you below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create a new type if you do a projection and return it form method!

```
public class MyCounts
{
    public string Topic { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}


public List<MyCounts> GetPopularTopics(int count)
{
    var posts = from p in db.Posts
                group p by p.Topic into myGroup
                select new MyCounts
                {
                    Topic = myGroup.Key,
                    Count = myGroup.Count()
                };
    return posts.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To create the grouping you create an anonymous type such as:

```
var posts = from p in context.Posts
            group p by p.Topic into topicCounts
            select new
            {
                Topic = topicCounts.Key,
                Count = topicCounts.Count()
            };
```

Then to work with the date, lets say iterate over it:

```
foreach(var p in posts)
{
    Response.Write(String.Format("{0} - {1}", p.Topic, p.Count));
}
```

Comment: What's an example of a query then? I'm getting issues with errors where I cannot implicitly convert that

Comment: like for example would I do a public <List>string? or how would i begin that query method?

Comment: Check my update, not sure if that is what you were referring to.

Comment: I meant like how would I go from Model > Controller > View if I'm using ASP.NET MVC3?

Comment: Umm, that does not help. The EF query will get data from your DB and that code should be in your model classes. The controller class should take this `posts` object and pass it to your view, and your view will do that writing on screen. However, there are an hundreds of ways to go about this, and this should get you through a basic scenario.

Comment: i understand how the EF query should be in the model classes, but my question is what is its return type? It won't just let me return an anonymous type

Comment: Oh, sorry I understand now. You can return `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, int>>` and call teh `ToList()` method on the `posts` objects

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you need to use an non anonymous type for your return value.

This query creates an IEnumerable of anonymous types.

```
var posts = from p in context.Posts
        group p by p.Topic into topicCounts
        select new
        {
            Topic = topicCounts.Key,
            Count = topicCounts.Count()
        };
```

It's the `select new` statement that creates the anonymous objects.

What you need to do is to create something that is non anonymous - an object that can be shared within and outside this method.

Like this:

```
public IEnumerable<TopicAndCount> GetPosts()
{
    var posts = from p in context.Posts
        group p by p.Topic into topicCounts
        select new TopicAndCount
        {
            Topic = topicCounts.Key,
            Count = topicCounts.Count()
        };
 }
```

Note the `select new TopicAndCount` statement and the return value of the enclosing method.

That will solve your problem.